# Expandable UITableView with "show more" button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The question is how i can done this?
[image]
and after pressing the button it must be following:
[image]

Comment: what you have tried yet????

Comment: you may use pagination for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement Such Functionality , the easiest way to do this :

1. First of all store only those data into array (or collection ) which needs to be displayed ( as for initial or less info )
2. Second Just implement an action on which , when **SHOW MORE** is cliicked just store all those data which needs to show and then [Tableview Reload].

Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

You need two types of cells. In the last cell put only label. You need also a flag in your view controller which remembers if the view if expanded or not.

Then you have to handle properly delegate methods of `UITableViewController` `(didSelectRowAtIndexPath, cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection)`

Answer (score 0):

To create Viewmore and Viewless in tableview cell you can try this approach:

if you are having only 1 section u can create a simple boolean property

`var isSectionsExpanded = false`

if the **isSectionsExpanded** is true 5 cells will be visible else 2 cells will be visible in your "**numberOfRowsInSection**"

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isSectionsExpanded ? 5 : 2 }
```

Now create a **footerView** that has a button like this

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: table.frame.width, height: 40))
    let showMoreOrLessButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (footerView.frame.width/2)-50, y: -1, width: 100, height: 20))
    showMoreOrLessButton.setTitle(isSectionsExpanded ? "View less" : "View more", for: .normal)
    showMoreOrLessButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewMoreButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    footerView.addSubview(showMoreOrLessButton)
    showMoreOrLessButton.tag = section
    return footerView
}
```

Now create a target method for the footer button like this

```
    @objc internal func viewMoreButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    isSectionsExpanded.toggle()
    tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sender.tag), with: .automatic) // Reload only the tapped section to update its cell count
}
```

thats it **Enjoy!!**